# Why are edit in place forms rendered together with the display version instead of being rendered on the fly?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, backbone.js, edit-in-place

Is there a specific reason that most everyone implements edit-in-place as a shown 'display' div and a hidden 'edit' div that are toggled on and off when somebody clicks on the associated 'edit' button like so?

```
<div id="title">
  <div class="display">
    <h1>
      My Title
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="edit">
    <input type="text" value="My Title" />
    <span class="save_edit_button"></span>
    <a href="#" class="cancel_edit">Cancel</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everywhere I look, I see edit-in-place basically handled like this. This approach certainly makes sense when you are rendering all views on the server side and delivering them to the client. However, with pure AJAX apps and frameworks like backbone.js, it seems that we could make our code much more DRY by rendering edit-in-place form elements on the fly as necessary, possibly even making a factory method that determines which form element to render. e.g.

- an H1 element with class "title" is replaced by `<input type="text" />`
- a span with class "year_founded" is replaced by `<input type="number" min="1900" max="2050" />`
- a span with class "price" is replaced by an input with the appropriate mask to only allow prices to be input.

Is this practice of rendering all edit-in-place form elements a historical legacy leftover from when pages were rendered on the server-side?

Given the flexibility and power we have with client-side MVC frameworks like Backbone.js, is there a reason for not creating and inserting the form elements on the fly when necessary using a factory method? Something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="description">
  Lorem ipsum dolar set amit...
</div>
<span class="edit_button"></span>
```

Backbone.js View

```
events: {
  "click .edit_button": "renderEditInPlaceForm",
},

renderEditInPlaceForm: function:(e) {
  var el = $(e.currentTarget).previous();
  var id = el.attr('id');
  var value = el.text();
  var tagName = el.tagName();
  var view  = new editInPlaceForm({   
    id: id,
    type: tagName,
    value: value
  });
  $("#id").html(view.render().el)
},
```

Where editInPlaceForm is a factory that returns the appropriate edit-in-place form element type based on tagName. This factory view also controls all its own logic for saving an edit, canceling an edit, making requests to the server and rerendering the appropriate original element that was replaced with the .html() function?

It seems to me that if we use this approach then we could also render the `<span class="edit_button"></span>` buttons on the fly based on a user's editing rights like so:

```
<h1 id="title">
  <%= document.get("title") %>
</h1>
<% if (user.allowedToEdit( document, title )) { %>
  <span class="edit_glyph"></span>  
<% } %>
```

where the allowedToEdit function on the user model accepts a model and attribute as its arguments.

Comment: Not sure where the question is. I do not know of any "best" solution for the exemple you put forward. Both seems ok to me. The only no-no thing you mentioned is having the javascript handle the privileges in your app. JS can be easily played with so make sure your backend doubles check all client changes.

Comment: @Julien Yes, we plan on having everything doubled checked server-side. All the privileges handling on the client-side is for usability and user experience issues. I don't want to render any elements on the page that the user cannot use. e.g. if they don't have edit privileges, then they should be able to see the edit button. My question is why have a "display" and "edit" div rendered on a page by default instead of using a factory to build the necessary edit-in-place form when needed?

Comment: I'm interested in knowing, as someone who is thinking about using Backbone for my app... seems to me your way makes sense, although I'm a bit confused about the "factory." Is that to reduce the "for this display view, render this named edit view" so you could say, "this display view is single-line text, factory please get me a single-line edit view"?

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting idea. The devil is in the detail.

While your simple example is easily rendered as an editable form on the fly, things quickly get trickier when dealing with other data types.

For example - suppose my edit form requires the user to choose a value from a `select` list.  On the display form I can simply display the user's choice, but for the edit form I am going to need those other available choices. Where do I hide them on the display? Similar issues exist for checkboxes, radio lists...

So, perhaps we should consider rendering the edit form, and then deriving our display-view from that?

Answer (score 0):

After 5 Backbone apps I came to same thoughts.

When things are complicated you have forms to show relations between user data,
but in simple cases you just need `input`, `select`, `checkbox` over `h1`, `div` or `span`

Now I am searching for jQuery plugin to make simple in place editing without ajax.
jQuery but not Backbone becuase I don't want to be tight coupled with Backbone for such small thing.

Likely to wright my own  jQuery + Synapse plugin http://bruth.github.com/synapse/docs/.

Synapse for binding with model and jQuery for input placing